Issue with Creating iSCSI Portal on TrueNAS SCALE
I am experiencing an issue with creating an iSCSI portal on my TrueNAS SCALE system using the IP address "192.168.10.14". Despite multiple attempts and troubleshooting steps, TrueNAS does not recognize the IP address as configured on the system.
System Configuration:

TrueNAS SCALE version: 24.04.0
Network Interface: enp6s19
IP Addresses on enp6s19:

192.168.10.14/24
fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 (IPv6)


iSCSI Configuration Attempt:
midclt call iscsi.portal.create '{"comment": "Portal for 192.168.10.14", "listen": [{"ip": "192.168.10.14"}]}'



Steps Taken:

Verified the IP addresses assigned to the interface using ip a show enp6s19.
Removed duplicate or unnecessary IP addresses to ensure only 192.168.10.14 is assigned.
Restarted the network interface with sudo ip link set enp6s19 down and sudo ip link set enp6s19 up.
Reloaded the network configuration in TrueNAS using midclt call network.reload.
Attempted to create the iSCSI portal with various commands:
midclt call iscsi.portal.create '{"comment": "Portal for 192.168.10.14", "listen": [{"ip": "192.168.10.14"}]}'

midclt call iscsi.portal.create '{"comment": "Portal for 192.168.10.14", "listen": [{"ip": "0.0.0.0", "interface": "enp6s19"}]}'

midclt call iscsi.portal.create '{"comment": "Portal for enp6s19", "listen": [{"interface": "enp6s19"}]}'



Error Message:
Each time I attempt to create the iSCSI portal, I receive the following error message:
[EINVAL] iscsiportal_create.listen: IP 192.168.10.14 not configured on this system.

Current Status:
Despite confirming that the IP address 192.168.10.14 is correctly assigned and active on the enp6s19 interface, TrueNAS still does not recognize it for iSCSI portal creation.
Request for Help:
I am looking for assistance to resolve this issue. Has anyone encountered a similar problem, or does anyone have suggestions on what might be going wrong?
Additional Information:

Output of ip a show enp6s19:
3: enp6s19: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.14/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global dynamic enp6s19
       valid_lft 83888sec preferred_lft 83888sec
    inet6 fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever



Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Here's how I solved this problem:
Set the desired network interface to use a static IP instead of DHCP. Be sure to configure the alias.
Once configured, the alias will appear in the iSCSI portal IP selection dropdown.
